# Status field couldnt fetch

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

Using **SphinxQl**, I could not fetch status fields from particular index. If I try to fetch the status fields, I will get following errors. Please any one help to solve that issue?

Example:

```
Select Status from tablename;
```

I got following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected STATUS, expecting IDENT (or 17 other tokens) near 'Status from tablename'.
```

Note:
  I could not insert any value at `STATUS` field in any index.

Answer (score 0):

STATUS is a reserved word , use `` `status` ``

Comment: Thanks its working .. Let me know what are the reservered words there in sphinxQL ?